# Exception occurred when adding lifecycle rule to delete all objects from S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to add a lifecycle rule to delete all objects inside an S3 bucket after a certain number of days. I get the following error when I execute my code. Could this be due to the target prefix being null??

Error:

**com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 4FR7C3BE85YVEW57; S3 Extended Request ID: fcYaw7u//7o843GjDtGGIQRjYxAMbn7f1iepEIas/Yt5bybM9BjDZ0JbG+SVz/vvE1k/KjaKadQ=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: fcYaw7u//7o843GjDtGGIQRjYxAMbn7f1iepEIas/Yt5bybM9BjDZ0JbG+SVz/vvE1k/KjaKadQ=**

Code used for creating and setting lifecycle rule to bucket configuration:

```
        try {
            BucketLifecycleConfiguration configuration = s3Client.getBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName);
            if (configuration == null) {
                BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                        .withId("Delete objects in " + expirationInDays + " days")
                        .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter())
                        .withExpirationInDays(expirationInDays)
                        .withExpiredObjectDeleteMarker(true)
                        .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED);

                configuration = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration()
                        .withRules(rule);
                s3Client.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName, configuration);
                configuration = s3Client.getBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName);
            } else {
                log.info("addLifecycleConfiguration: Lifecycle rules found in configuration. Skipping.");
            }
        } catch (AmazonClientException ex) {
            log.error("addLifecycleConfiguration: AmazonClientException. ex={}", ex.getMessage());
        }
```

[image: Debug output]

Comment: Are you using CDK to provision a bucket outside the app or SDK to create a bucket inside your app?

Comment: @jarmod I'm trying to delete all objects in the S3 bucket. What other prefix do I specify for my use case??

Comment: Interestingly, a reported [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1438) suggests that an empty filter should be supplied. It then suggests doing this with a filter predicate that has an empty prefix, much as you are doing. And [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html) also says to use an absent prefix while [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html) says to specify an empty filter. Have you tried passing a null filter? Also, have you tried a null prefix instead of ""?

Comment: @adityaViswanatham I added both v1 and v2 SDK solutions. Did either work for you?

Comment: @jarmod I'm sorry for the late reply. The problem was having withExpiredObjectDeleteMarker() in the lifecycle rule. Instead setting .withExpiredNonCurrentVerions() to true helped fix the issue. Not sure why that's the case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work with the AWS Java SDK v1, as follows:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.BucketLifecycleConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.lifecycle.LifecycleFilter;

public class App {

     public static void setLifecycle(AmazonS3 s3, String bucketName) {

        try {
            // Create a rule to delete all objects after 30 days.
            BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                    .withId("Delete objects in 30 days")
                    .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter())
                    .withExpirationInDays(30)
                    .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED);

            BucketLifecycleConfiguration configuration = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration()
                    .withRules(rule);
            s3.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName, configuration);
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        setLifecycle(s3, "mybucket");
    }
}
```

The code basically creates a default, empty filter rule instead of a prefix filter on "".

I was also able to get this to work with the current Java SDK v2, as follows.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.BucketLifecycleConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ExpirationStatus;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.LifecycleRuleFilter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.LifecycleRule;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.LifecycleExpiration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest;

import java.util.Collections;

public class App {

     public static void setLifecycle(S3Client s3, String bucketName) {

        try {
            // Create a rule to delete all objects after 30 days.
            LifecycleRule rule = LifecycleRule.builder()
                    .id("Delete after 30 days rule")
                    .filter(LifecycleRuleFilter.builder().build())
                    .expiration(LifecycleExpiration.builder().days(30).build())
                    .status(ExpirationStatus.ENABLED)
                    .build();

            BucketLifecycleConfiguration lifecycleConfiguration = BucketLifecycleConfiguration.builder()
                    .rules(Collections.singletonList(rule))
                    .build();

            PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest request = PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .lifecycleConfiguration(lifecycleConfiguration)
                    .build();

            s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(request);
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
        setLifecycle(s3, "mybucket");
        s3.close();
    }
}
```

I came to this conclusion because, after manually configuring a similar lifecycle in the AWS Console, the awscli description of that lifecycle configuration looked like this:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket mybucket
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 30
            },
            "ID": "del30",
            "Filter": {},
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see the same error even with the empty filer rule.

Comment: Can you update your post to show what code change you made? This v2 code works.

Comment: Enabled debug level logs. This is what is seen: `<LifecycleConfiguration><Rule><ID>Delete objects in 1 days</ID><Status>Enabled</Status><Filter></Filter><Expiration><Days>1</Days><ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker>true</ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker></Expiration></Rule></LifecycleConfiguration>`

Comment: This is the aws sdk version I'm using in the project.
`implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.496")`